# Fetch all records from HBase using SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read all records from Hbase table. Below is the code snippet.

```
    SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf);

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);

    Configuration hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    hbaseConf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000");
    hbaseConf.setInt("timeout", 120000);
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    hbaseConf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
    hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "Test");

    DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class), TestBean.class);

    df.registerTempTable("TempTest");
    df.show();
```

At  `df.show()` i am getting below error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`

Any pointers, why i am facing this issue.

Comment: The stack trace would help, but I suspect you have mismatched versions of libraries somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a DataFrame from a RDD composed of pairs:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable     
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
```

You need to read your hBaseRDD:

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, classOf[TableInputFormat], 
  classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]);
```

Then transform (ImmutableBytesWritable, Result) tuples into an RDD of Result:

```
val resultRDD = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)
```

Then transform into an RDD of Rows that can be converted into a DataFrame.

As an example we suppose that you have a HBase table with a key that contains two values 'value1_value2', you could parse the Key (sperated by '_') using:

```
val keyValueRDD = resultRDD.map(result =>     (Bytes.toString(result.getRow()).split("_")(0),   Bytes.toString(result.getRow()).split("_")(1), Bytes.toFloat(result.value())))
```

Now you can create a dataframe with the values in your '_' separated key:

```
   import sqlContext.implicits._
   val df = keyValueRDD.toDF("value1", "value2");
   df.registerTempTable("Table")
   sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Table Limit 5").show()
```

In order to fully map your HBase table to a DataFrame you need:

1. **Create a case class**: (Outside your object)

   ```
    case class TestRow(rowkey: String, value1: String, value2: String, value3: Float, value4: Float)
   ```
2. **Define your column family as Bytes**:

   ```
   final val cfTest = "te"
   final val cfTestBytes = Bytes.toBytes(cfTest)
   ```
3. **Parse the Results**:

   ```
     object TestRow {
       def parseTestRow(result: Result): TestRow = {
         val rowkey = Bytes.toString(result.getRow())

         val p0 = rowkey
         val p1 = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(cfTestBytes, Bytes.toBytes("currency")))
         val p2 = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(cfTestBytes, Bytes.toBytes("asat")))
         val p3 = Bytes.toFloat(result.getValue(cfTestBytes, Bytes.toBytes("m_aed")))
         val p4 = Bytes.toFloat(result.getValue(cfTestBytes, Bytes.toBytes("m_usd")))
         TestRow(p0, p1, p2, p3, p4)
       }
     }
   ```
4. **Create a Dataframe**

   ```
   val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, classOf[TableInputFormat], 
   classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
   classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]);  

   val resultRDD = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)
   val testRDD = resultRDD.map(TestRow.parseTestRow)
   import sqlContext.implicits._
   val testDF = testRDD.toDF()
   testDF.registerTempTable("Test")
   sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM Test").show()
   ```